# Assign a IGeometry to Feature.Shape

Tags: shapefile, arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, geometry

I'm trying insert a feature into a FeatureClass, but when I try to assign the geometry to featurebuffer the app return the next Error:  The remote procedure call failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BE)

```c#
IWorkspaceEdit workspaceEdit = (IWorkspaceEdit)this._getWorkSpaceFromArcSDE();

workspaceEdit.StartEditing(true);
workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();

IFeatureClass fc = this.getFeatureClassFromArcSDE(layerName);
IFeatureCursor pFeatureCursor;
IFeatureBuffer pFeatureBuffer;
IFeature pFeature;

QueryFilter qf = QueryFilter)_pServerContext.CreateObject("esriGeodatabase.QueryFilter");
qf.WhereClause = "";
pFeatureCursor = fc.Search(qf, false);
pFeature = pFeatureCursor.NextFeature();

if (pFeature != null) pFeature.Delete();

pFeatureBuffer = fc.CreateFeatureBuffer();
pFeatureCursor = fc.Insert(true);

**pFeatureBuffer.Shape = geometry;** //Here return the error

pFeatureCursor.InsertFeature(pFeatureBuffer);
pFeatureCursor.Flush();

workspaceEdit.StopEditOperation();
workspaceEdit.StopEditing(true);

Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pFeatureCursor);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(pFeatureBuffer);
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(fc);
```

Comment: The first thing I would check is to see if geometry has been set and it is an appropriate type (i.e. you are not trying to store a polygon when it should be a point?

Comment: geometry is not set or declared.  Where is it coming from and what's in it?

Comment: be sure geometry is of type IGeometry or one of the co-classes that implement it (e.g. IPolygon, IPolyline etc...)

Comment: Sorry, this is a function which hava as parameters: IGeometry geometry and string layerName.